# How to make automatic headings of subsections from inside a loop (R markdown, Rmd, knitr)

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I need to construct a template for automatic analysis. I wonder, how can I make headings of subsections from inside a loop in `.Rmd` file, so that they could be included in either a table of contents (in HTML, e.g., file) or other kind of navigation bar. Number of subsections is not known in advance.

I imagine, the code in `.Rmd` file should look like following, where function or method `make_hyperlink_to` is needed:

````
Introduction
============
/... some text .../

Analysis
============
```{r body of analysis}
    n = 1:3 # number of subsections
    for (i in n) {
        name_of_subsection <- paste("Subsection", i)
        make_hyperlink_to(name_of_subsection)       # <----- 
        print("/... some results .../")       
    }
```
````

The result should be something like:

## Introduction

/... some text .../

## Analysis

### Subsection 1

/... some results .../

### Subsection 2

/... some results .../

### Subsection 3

/... some results .../

Comment: I bet there a several different (possibly better) ways to do this, but once upon a time I used `brew` for a similar task ([**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173199/brew-and-knit-one-pdf-report-split-by-variable-with-special-characters-%C3%A5-%C3%A6-%C3%B8), strongly inspired by [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316529/loops-with-captions-with-knitr/14342296#14342296)).

Comment: maybe a cludge, but you could write a .R file that does the looping and writes/generates the .Rmd?

Comment: Do you simply mean [this](http://pastebin.com/14MAUJu5)?